# Dividing conditioned probability into separate probability terms

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have a conditioned probability problem as following:

$P(x|y,z,k)$

if $z$ and $k$ are independent and there is not any correlation between them, can I write the problem as following:

$P(x|y,z,k)=P(x|y,z)P(x|y,k)$

Is it a true statement?

Answer (score 1):

No, this statement is incorrect. If $Z$ and $K$ are independent, the joint density of $(X,Y,Z,K)$ simplifies into
$$p(z)p(k)p(y|z,k)p(x|y,z,k)$$but this does not change the conditional density of $X$. In any addition, a density in $x$ like the lhs is rarely equal to a product of two densities in $x$ like the rhs, an exception being when all three terms are constant (uniform distribution).